Spring Boot: Integration tests using Testcontainers fail when using spring.data.mongodb.uri property, but work when using spring.data.mongodb.user etc
I have a set of working integration tests with Testcontainers and MongoDB container. As part of the test, an data import is done when running tests. For this, I've written a configuration class:
@ActiveProfiles({ "test", "integration" })
@TestConfiguration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class TestContainersConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ServiceConnection
    public MongoDBContainer mongoDbContainer() throws UnsupportedOperationException, IOException, InterruptedException {

        var mongoDBContainer = new MongoDBContainer(DockerImageName.parse("mongo:4.4"));

        mongoDBContainer.start();
        mongoDBContainer.copyFileToContainer(MountableFile.forClasspathResource("testResources.json"),
                "/publications.json");
        mongoDBContainer.execInContainer("mongoimport",
                "--db", "documents",
                "--mode", "upsert",
                "--collection", "dspacePublication", "--file",
                "/publications.json", "--jsonArray", "--quiet");

        return mongoDBContainer;

    }

}

My integration test all extend an abstract class:
@ActiveProfiles({ "test", "integration" })
@Import(TestContainersConfiguration.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    protected MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Autowired
    protected MongoDBContainer mongoDBContainer;

    @BeforeEach
    protected void beforeEach() throws UnsupportedOperationException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        assertTrue(mongoDBContainer.isRunning());

    }

}

This is one of the integration test classes:
@ActiveProfiles({ "test", "integration" })
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SearchControllerIT extends AbstractIntegrationTest {

        private List<Publication> publications;

        @BeforeEach
        public void setUp() throws Exception {

                this.publications = super.mongoTemplate.findAll(Publication.class);
                assertFalse(publications.isEmpty(), "an empty list of publications was returned when querying test MongoDB!");

 
        }

        // test methods
}

All of my integration tests run, when I use dedicated MongoDB connection details in application.properties (using environment variables to allow overriding):
spring.data.mongodb.database=${SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_DATABASE:documents}
spring.data.mongodb.host=${SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_HOST:mongodb}
spring.data.mongodb.port=${SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_PORT:27017}

However, they fail when replacing this properties by:
spring.data.mongodb.uri=${SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI:mongodb://mongodb:27017/documents}

In this case, mongoTemplate.findAll(Publication.class) returns an empty list.
It looks like "@ServiceConnection" does not override spring.data.mongodb.uri, so the one from application.properties takes precedence.
How can I make integration tests run while keeping spring.data.mongodb.uri in application.properties?

@ServiceConnection will define a MongoConnectionDetails bean that's backed by the test container. Spring Boot's auto-configuration will use these details to connect to Mongo. Perhaps you're not using the auto-configuration to set up the Mongo-related beans and something else is doing so and isn't using the connection details? A minimal, reproducible example would clear this up.

@AndyWilkinson The code in my request is fairly complete. As you can see, SearchControllerIT uses auto-configuration. I can however not provide the content of file "testResources", but that should be irrelevant.
Is there a way to "dump" the connection details that are used by Spring's MongoTemplate?

Unfortunately, fairly complete leaves too many unknowns and it's hard to justify spending time answering questions that rely on guesswork.
